# can we debug native script mobile app on chrome dev tool?

Tags: angular, mobile, google-chrome-devtools, nativescript, hybrid-mobile-app

I working on mobile application and using nativescript for that. I'm mainly using ios platform. I want to know is there any way to debug this app on chrome developer tools ?
I need to check network tab because I'm finding very hard to debug network calls in this kind of application.